# Получить имена тегов - хук - постинг - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hook

1) Создаем новый пост тайтл, текст, теги

2) Как в файле function.php получить с помощью хука имена тегов до того как они запишутся в базу данных

3) Как в файле function.php получить с помощью хука имена тегов после того как они записались в базу

И главный вопрос, на каком вобще этапе их можно получить ?

Answer (score 0):

2. <del>никак</del>. Возможно update_term_meta() поможет. но вряд ли.
3. [wp_get_post_tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_tags/) и множество др функций с вхождением `tag`. Смотря для чего "получить".

Искать в [новом кодексе](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/) на англ или в [вольном переводе на русский](https://wp-kama.ru/functions) (может быть не полно и устаревшее. При применении стоит сравнивать с оф. манами)

Comment: Вопрос в том, можно ли получить это значение ДО записи его в базу ? Дело в том что var_dump показывает тольок post data, и все, а в post data нету информации о тегах. Дело в том что, все работает из function.php, попробую создать пример, плагина и запустить оттуда, возможно function.php срабатывает слишком рано и  таких данных у него просто нет, как теги и т д. А есть только post дата

Comment: Просто в function.php получание тегов идет еще на более низком уровне, но как их получить я не знаю. Максимум что я могу получить из всех отправляемых данных это POST DATA, т.е post-id post-title post-content и т д, теги в эти данные не входят.

Comment: Может стоит не придумывать пути решения, а просто спрашивать решение главной задачи?

Comment: Давайте, задача, при постинге статьи, до вывода сообщения (об успешном постинге) хуком прехватить данные поста, а именно: тайтл, пермалинг (с реврайтом) и теги. С помощью какого хука это сделать ? посмотрите в сторону wp_insert_post_data но он вам не отдаст ТЕГИ и Пермалинк (с реврайтом) тоже. только guid линк типа www.site.com/?p=233

Comment: "Перехватить" - это (кривой?) путь решения ГЛАВНОЙ задачи. О ней ничего нет. Да и собсно это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: Почему это кривой ? При нажатии на кнопку публиковать, я отправляю вызываю функцию публикации в соц-сеть ссылки новости. Как Вы предлагаете решить данную задачу ? Сначала нажать опубликовать, а потом если пост опубликован выводить кнопочку опубликовать в соц сети ?

Comment: Естественно, отправлять что-то на сторону нужно только после того, как всё опубликуется на сайте. Вот "публикация в соц-сеть" и есть главная задача, а никак не "перехватить". И вообще эта задача давно решена множеством плагинов. Но если хочется своих велосипедов - можно и спросить на СО как это делать правильно. Только отдельным вопросом.

Comment: Да, но Вы попробуйде получить теги, в function.php когда пост в статусе publish. - это главная задача. Статус publish означает что пост опубликован именно к этому статусу и "привязанна" функция отправки поста в соц-сети. Что по поводу велосипеда, то все сайте в интернете, это большой велосипед, только блестит по разному )